# MVC Child action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one-page app, and some dockpanel as partial view that it's content renders some action like this:

```
Html.RenderAction(ViewData["action"].ToString(), ViewData["controller"].ToString(), new { Index = indexPart});
```

Sometimes it renders "general" action that need to redirect to some another action:

```
TShortCutMenu shortCutMenu = _kwd.TShortCutMenu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ShortCutMenuID == shortCutID);

return RedirectToAction(shortCutMenu.ActionName, shortCutMenu.ControllerName, new { id = ctrlValue });
```

And now of course I receive the exception: "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions".

How can I redirect to another action from the child one?

Comment: how about removing the childAction filter

Comment: i tried, it didn't help

Comment: one thing that works for me - is return the empty view that only renders needed action, but to be honest I don't know is this a good idea...